# How to get independent virtual desktops on multiple monitors?

Tags: linux, desktop-environment, multi-monitor

I have two monitors and I want every desktop to be independent on every screen.

Like this: https://www.actualtools.com/virtualdesktops/independent_virtual_desktops_on_multiple_monitors.shtml

How can this be done on Linux?

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you are trying to do. Include it in you question. I am not going to read a long MS article, before answering your question.

Comment: Are you looking for different keyboard/mouse/user per monitor? Ability to switch virtual desktop on each monitor independently, but both monitors are in the same user session, and windows can/cannot/don't-care be dragged from monitor to monitor.

Comment: Which desktop should a window that spans two monitors be in? And I found a setting in one of the task-managers for plasma. It has the option to only show windows from current screen (not exactly what you were looking for).

Answer (score 2):

you may have a look at https://www.enlightenment.org/
The only window manager I know of which allows you to have 
independent virtual desktops for each monitor/screen.

```
mon1=screen1      mon2=screen2 
-------------     -------------
| 1-0 | 1-1 |     | 2-0 | 2-1 |
-------------     -------------
| 1-3 | 1-4 |     | 2-3 | 2-4 |
-------------     -------------
```

Lets say you have the following elements on your screen

- screen1 = 1-0
- screen2 = 2-3

if you now switch screen1 to 1-3 than screen2 stays where it is at 2-3
same holds true if you now move screen2 to 2-4 than screen1 stays where you set it last as 1-3

You can easily move an application from 1-0 to 2-3 and also copy/paste works across all screens as it is just on X-Server

However you can NOT move the screen 2-x to the mon1 (kind of makes sense)

I like this setup and I run it within 3 physical monitors

If there are other Windowmanager which can do this
I would like to know

Was not able to implement that with (maybe due to lack of skill on my side)

- Awesome
- Gnome
- FVWM2
- evilvm

Comment: Thanks, in fact coming back from macOS (I used KDE extensively before 10y) I was shocked about this "inflexibility" of most WMs. They can say what they want about X-standards, but it is highly annoying. I use 2 monitors to have an overview between left-right, and I should not need to move my windows around if I happen to have them on the "wrong" v-desktop... I guess it's bye KWIN after 3 hours of usage. I used to want to like Enlightenment (in the DR17 days), but the "integrated" DE experience was too incomplete, I fear it still is...

Answer (score 1):

Independent virtual desktops are herein defined.

1. A virtual desktop consists of one monitor, and wherein user possesses more than one monitor, they can change the set of applications displayed on one monitor without changing the rest
2. The same names can be assigned to virtual desktops on 2 or more monitors. EG both monitor one and monitor two can each have their own desktop 1,2,3…N
3. Implemented via tags eg each window has one or more tags and displaying a tag  on a monitor displays all windows  that possess said tag allowing you to effectively include a window in multiple "desktops"

By having independent namespaces for each display one gets more spaces that can be easily reachable with hotkeys eg super+0-9 and flexibility. The cost is that to navigate via keyboard one must constantly switch monitors and then switch desktops. eg given 3 monitors arranged x y z navigating from x1->z9 one might do super+l super+l super+9.

This flexibility is, therefore, a misfeature. It's far better to assign different desktops to each monitor so that one can go from x1->z9 with one invocation of super+9. If one feels that 10 is too few desktops for n monitors, there is nothing requiring one to use only numbers as letters work just fine as well.

There are many window managers that satisfy 1 and fewer that satisfy 2 however if you desire either option can be forced to behave like the other.

If you want type one to act as if it were two bind desktop x0-9 to monitor x and y0-9 to y and have your hotkey consider your present monitor when switching eg super+3 on y would switch to y3 and on x would switch to x3.

If you want type two to act as one have your switch workspace function, consider the target eg 3 and automatically switch to the correct monitor itself.

1. i3wm bspwm sway
2. dwm
3. awesome, xmodad

Regarding actualtools I see a lot of folks coming from mediocre tools who are looking not for a good solution but for a solution that works as much like the tool they are coming from misfeatures, quirks, and all. They are oft dissatisfied because few tools are apt to aim to faithfully emulate their inferiors. Greater satisfaction can be obtained by understanding and learning native tools as they are rather than trying to find exact replacements.